# HTML/Bootstrap layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, layout, html-lists

I'm trying to layout a section like the image here.

[image: list of items]

I'm using bootstrap 4. I've tried laying out with rows and cols but can never achieve this look. Right now I'm using a `<ul>` and `<li>`. Inside the `<li>` I have 3 inputs. I've tried putting all three inside a `<div class="form-group form-inline">` and also tried separating them out to individual "form-group" divs with no luck. I'm sure I just don't understand enough about how to lay things out. I'm hoping someone can help me understand and maybe help me out here.

This is as close as I have come but I can't seem to get the widths correct and it seems to break onto the new line.

```
<div id="cardBody" class="card-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label ml-2">Description</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label">Link</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <label class="control-label">Count</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form>
        <ul id="itemList" class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="form-group form-inline mb-0">
              <label for="description">&#8942;&#8942;</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control ml-2 mr-2" id="description" placeholder="">

              <label class="sr-only" for="link">Link</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="link" placeholder="">

              <label class="sr-only" for="count">Count</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="count" placeholder="">
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="form-group form-inline mb-0">
              <label for="description2">&#8942;&#8942;</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control ml-2 mr-2" id="description2" placeholder="">

              <label class="sr-only" for="link2">Link</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="link2" placeholder="">

              <label class="sr-only" for="count2">Count</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="count2" placeholder="">
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">&#8942;&#8942;</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">4</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">5</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">6</li>
        </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: closest attempt]

Anyway, thanks in advance for any help or insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. You may want to put the inline styles in your css file.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="cardBody" class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container-fluid d-flex">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <label class="control-label ml-4">Description</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label class="control-label">Link</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <label class="control-label">Count</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <form>
          <ul id="itemList" class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7 form-group form-inline mb-0">
                  <div class="d-flex" style="width: 100%;">
                    <label for="description">&#8942;&#8942;</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ml-2" id="description" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 form-group form-inline mb-0" style="width: 100%;">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="link" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 form-group form-inline mb-0" style="width: 100%;">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="count" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7 form-group form-inline mb-0">
                  <div class="d-flex" style="width: 100%;">
                    <label for="description">2</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ml-2" id="description" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 form-group form-inline mb-0" style="width: 100%;">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="link" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 form-group form-inline mb-0" style="width: 100%;">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="count" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7 form-group form-inline mb-0">
                  <div class="d-flex" style="width: 100%;">
                    <label for="description">3</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ml-2" id="description" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 form-group form-inline mb-0" style="width: 100%;">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="link" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 form-group form-inline mb-0" style="width: 100%;">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="count" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7 form-group form-inline mb-0">
                  <div class="d-flex" style="width: 100%;">
                    <label for="description">4</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ml-2" id="description" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 form-group form-inline mb-0" style="width: 100%;">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="link" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 form-group form-inline mb-0" style="width: 100%;">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="count" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7 form-group form-inline mb-0">
                  <div class="d-flex" style="width: 100%;">
                    <label for="description">5</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ml-2" id="description" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 form-group form-inline mb-0" style="width: 100%;">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="link" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 form-group form-inline mb-0" style="width: 100%;">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="count" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```